# Replace attribute value in HTML to load in webview

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

Loading local HTML in webview

```
        appfolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        xmlFile = await appfolder.GetFileAsync("000Title.html");
        using (Stream stream = await xmlFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            //stream.Read
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.Async = true;
            settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings))
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "img")
                    {
                        string  attributeValue = reader.GetAttribute("src"); // img elemeent 
                        string val = attributeValue;
                        StorageFile file = await appfolder.GetFileAsync(attributeValue);
                        using (var stream1 = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
                        {
                            var reader1 = new DataReader(stream1.GetInputStreamAt(0));
                            var bytes = new byte[stream1.Size];
                            await reader1.LoadAsync((uint)stream1.Size);
                            reader1.ReadBytes(bytes);
                            string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                            string Base = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64;
                         }
```

Here I am replacing attribute "Src" value with base64 string.

```
       attributeValue = attributeValue.Replace(attributeValue,Base);
       html = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(xmlFile);
       view.NavigateToString(html);
```

Here I am loading the HTML in webview, But it is displaying with previous value.

**UPDATE: Don't specify to use library like Html Agility Pack**

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading the file into the `reader` object. You're extracting the attribute into the `attributeValue` string. You're then updating that string. But you never write the string back out again  - somewhat understandable, since an XmlReader only gives you the ability to read.

The bottom line is that the file is never changed. So when you load the file again into the `html` string, it's obviously still going to have the original content.

I would suggest loading the from the `reader` into an `XmlDocument` object. You can then manipulate the document and write it out again with the `Save` method.